# Is there a RAD for Android?

Tags: android

Anything to help design GUI like a paint program? (Delphi, VB, MSVC, QtBuilder, etc)

And anything to help build packages, set permissions, etc?

What is there out there to take the drudge work out of Android app creation and leave me free to concentrate on design and development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DroidDraw, already mentioned, can help for the GUI. It now supports a few more root layouts, including ScrollView and TableLayout. It doesn't do much that can't be done in Eclipse, though.

Google is doing some research on a wysiwyg editor called App Inventor but if it does come out it's unlikely to be soon.
*Edit*: Spoke too soon, App Inventor's already out [here](http://sites.google.com/site/appinventorhelp/)

Try to take the time to get used to the tool (Android Eclipse plugin), it already takes care of a lot for you.

Answer (score 4):

Basic4Android, www.basic4ppc.com check it out, it compiles directly to native java (dex) with a visual designer.

Answer (score 1):

For GUI, you can try Droiddraw but I wouldn't recommend it. Last time I checked it only support AbsoluteLayout.

For the others, I found its a breeze using Eclipse, so I don't really know if there's any.

Answer (score 1):

The official Android plugin for Eclipse contains everything you want.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi for Android sneak preview: http://www.lenniedevilliers.net/preview/DAndroid_01.avi

Comment: +! Whoo hoo! I love Delphi. thanks!